# How do I evaluate $\int \frac{dz}{\sqrt{z}}$?

Tags: integration, complex-analysis

The original integral is:

$$\int \frac{dz}{\sqrt{z}}$$

if area is a half-circle $\{|z| = 1; y \ge 0; \sqrt{1} = -1\}$

I was thinking of Euler's formula $e^{it} = \cos t + i\sin t$

and with idea that $z = x + iy$ take $y \ge 0$ from here somehow, but I am not sure, and also have problem with understanding $\sqrt{1} = -1$ condition.

Comment: $\frac1{\sqrt z}$ has primitive 2$\sqrt z$.

Comment: @user128766, so you used only newton-leibnitz's formula because function is analytical, ok, but maybe you know how to interpretate $\sqrt{1} = -1$ and $y \ge 0$) (I have 6 more different conditions for this integral, so I am confused)

Comment: Your question is highly unclear. $\int \frac{dz}{\sqrt{z}}$ is the indefinite integral of a single-variable function, which equals $C+2\sqrt{z}$. If you want to compute something else, please use the appropriate notation, like $$ \iint_D f(x,y)\,dx\,dy $$ for denoting the integral of a two-variables function over some domain $D$.